# ImportError cannot import name check_login in django

Tags: python, django, importerror

I have a check_login function in view module of django app named- `userdata` as shown below:

```
def check_login(request):
    user_dict={}
    cookieid=request.COOKIES.get('usercookie',None)
    if cookieid is not None and cookieid :     
        u = UserDetails.objects.filter(uid=cookieid)
        if u.exists():
            user_dict['user']=u[0]
            status=True
        else:
            status=False
    else:
        status=False

    user_dict['cid']=cid
    user_dict['login_status']=status
    return user_dict
```

And i am trying to import it in another package as :  
`from userdata.views import check_login`
but showing error.
All other functions from the same python_module could be imported except the function described above . what is wrong here ,why it couldn't be imported[image: import error shown]

import usage :
in trello apps' view:
`from userdata.views import check_login`

in userdata apps' view:
`from trello.views import tr_ui`
error occurance in 1st import of check_login

Comment: Can you import userdata.views?

Comment: i have imported other methods from this view,., but when i tried to import userdata.views itself , it was not possible.,.,why..so?

Comment: Maybe there is a circular import. What is the full track?

Comment: Are you using python 3? If so, then try "from . import userdata.views", else try "from userdata import views", if all has failed, check if you can import userdata itself by "import userdata"

Comment: yes finally figured out....!!!   there was a circular import ,.,.in that case what should i do....??????  i need both imports ,.,.

Comment: You can use a local import to avoid it.

Comment: how local import,.,.both methods are in views module of different apps.,.so is it possible in anyway..??

Comment: Instead of having `from userdata.views import check_login` at the top of your file, you can put it just before you call the check_login method 
`def my_view(request):
    from userdata.views import check_login
    check_login(request)`

Comment: gr8 thanks,.,it worked,.,. but i am using check_login method in more than 1 method , so would i need to import everywhere and if so ,.,wouldn't it violate dry approach ,., or i could do local import for the least used  view-method.,.,

Answer (score 0):

as pointed out by [trnsnt](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1090357/trnsnt)

the problem was circular import : 
in userdata app trello's view was called
`from userdata.views import check_login`
and
in trello app uderdata's view was called
`from trello.views import tr_ui`

if both imports are required then 1 can use local import instead of calling on top of the page as :

```
def trello_action(request):
    from userdata.views import check_login
    user_dict=check_login(request)
```

this solves the circular import problem

Comment: Note: you don't need that to solve the circular import. You could just do `from userdata import views` and then use `views.check_login` instead of plain `check_login`. This works if you aren't using `check_login` at the top level, but only inside function definitions.